# Don't submit form unless text field has more than 2 characters

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have this simple form for my websites search (Wordpress)

```
<form action="/" method="get">
    <label for="search">Search</label>
    <input type="text" name="s" id="search" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" />
    <input type="image" class="search-btn" alt="Search" src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/img/magnifier13.png" width="16" height="16" />
</form>
```

I don't want people to be able to search for anything without putting less than 2 characters in the search field, How do I go about doing this? preferably with JS.

Comment: check the length of the textbox on submit button click

Comment: Did you try something? You could really just use google for this one

Comment: simple html required attribute will be enough.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `pattern` attribute of HTML5. The `required` attribute is also needed, otherwise an input field with an empty value will be excluded from constraint validation.

```
<input pattern=".{2,}"   required title="2 characters minimum">
<input pattern=".{3,10}" required title="3 to 10 characters">
```

Comment: for use of default validator +1

Answer (score 1):

You can simply call a javascript code for checking the length of textbox before submitting form.

```
<form action="/" method="get" onsubmit="return (document.getElementById('search').value.length > 2);">
```

Comment: nice solutions :) hope that wont affect any other jwuery

Comment: Why do you need to look up the element by id?

Comment: so do i @Sac, long live Bear Grylls :P

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#SubmitButtonId').Click(function(){
  var myLength = $("#search").val().length;
  if(myLength < 3)
  {
    //show message
  }
  else
  {
    //submit form
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the forms `onsubmit` event to prevent submission if the length is less than the defined amount:

```
<form action="/" method="get" onsubmit="return (this.s.value.length > 2);">
    <label for="search">Search</label>
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript you can check for the length of the search text box and see if it is more than 2 characters. If it's more than 2, then go ahead with the search:

```
  document.getElementsByClassName('test').onClick =function(){
        if(document.getElementById('search').text.length <= 2){
            alert("Needs more than two characters to do search);
        else{
            // commence search
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do something like this:

```
<form action="/" method="get">
    <label for="search">Search</label>
    <input type="text" name="s" id="search" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" />
    <input type="image" class="search-btn" alt="Search" src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/img/magnifier13.png" width="16" height="16" />

    <input type='button' onclick='checkBeforeSubmit();'>
</form>


// somewhere in your javascript code:

var checkBeforeSubmit = function(){
    var text = $("#search").val();
    if(text.length > 2)
        $(form).submit();
}
```